# Javascript - pass variables to a url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass some form variables to populate a url. As long as I have only one variable, the script works. As soon as I start adding more than one variable, it breaks and the button does not do anything onClick. What is wrong with my script?

```
function ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument()
{
var onBaseServer = "tudwv-emc01.dong.com";
var appName = "LawsonDev";
var screenID = "AP90";
    var accField = "InvoiceNum";
    var accField1 = "VendorID";
    var company = lawForm.getDataValue("API-COMPANY");
    var ProcLvl = lawForm.getDataValue("API-PROC-LEVEL");
    var sINVNumber = lawForm.getDataValue("API-INVOICE");
    var sVenNumber = lawForm.getDataValue("API-VENDOR");

if (sINVNumber == "")
{
    portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox("Please inquire on a valid invoice 
    first.","ok","info",window,false)
    return true;
}
    var encINVNumber = encodeURIComponent(portalWnd.strTrim(sINVNumber));

var s = "http://"
    + onBaseServer
    + "/OnBaseLinkWebPOC/AccLogin.aspx?DBID="
    + appName
    + "&ScreenID="
    + screenID
    + "&Company="
    + company
    + "&ProcLvl="
    + ProcLvl
    + &
    + accField1
    + "="
    + sVenNumber
    + &
    + accField
    + "="
    + sINVNumber;

 //portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox(s,"ok","info",window,false)

 window.open(s);
 return true;

 }
```

Comment: What’s `+ &` supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to be `"&"` I presume.

Comment: Needs more `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: It needs more of many things..

Comment: Adds & to the url. For example: the url is http://tudwv-emc01.dong.com/OnBaseLinkWebPOC/AccLogin.aspx?DBID=LawsonDev&ScreenID=AP90&Company=11&ProcLvl=11&VendorID=7654321&InvoiceNum=1212121

Comment: @Shaji That’d be `+ "&"`. I don’t even want to imagine what JavaScript would make of `<string> + & + <string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had quite a few syntactical errors. Otherwise, you're fine.

Make sure to use `encodeURIComponent()` more often for URL parameters.

P.S: `window.open()` doesn't work if you have any ad-blocker enabled or installed. Disable temporarily and it should work.

```js
function ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument() {
  var onBaseServer = "tudwv-emc01.dong.com";
  var appName = "LawsonDev";
  var screenID = "AP90";
  var accField = "InvoiceNum";
  var accField1 = "VendorID";
  var company = "MyCompany";
  var ProcLvl = "5";
  var sINVNumber = "7567567567";
  var sVenNumber = "36456346436";

  if (sINVNumber == "") {
    portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox("Please inquire on a valid invoice first. ", "ok", "info", window, false);
    return true;
  }
  //var encINVNumber = encodeURIComponent(portalWnd.strTrim(sINVNumber));

  var s = "http://" +
    encodeURIComponent(onBaseServer) +
    "/OnBaseLinkWebPOC/AccLogin.aspx?DBID=" +
    encodeURIComponent(appName) +
    "&ScreenID=" +
    encodeURIComponent(screenID) +
    "&Company=" +
    encodeURIComponent(company) +
    "&ProcLvl=" +
    encodeURIComponent(ProcLvl) +
    "&" +
    encodeURIComponent(accField1) +
    "=" +
    encodeURIComponent(sVenNumber) +
    "&" +
    encodeURIComponent(accField) +
    "=" +
    encodeURIComponent(sINVNumber);

  //portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox(s,"ok","info",window,false)

  window.open(s, "My Invoice");
  console.log(s);
  return true;
}

ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use [Template Literals / Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) there to make your life much easier.

```
var s = encodeURIComponent(`http://${onBaseServer}/OnBaseLinkWebPOC/AccLogin.aspx?DBID=${appName}&ScreenID=${screenID}&Company=${company}&ProcLvl=${ProcLvl}&${accField1}=${sVenNumber}&${accField}=${sINVNumber}`);
```

Comment: Was just about to mention URI encoding. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument() {
      var onBaseServer = "tudwv-emc01.dong.com";
      var appName = "LawsonDev";
      var screenID = "AP90";
      var accField = "InvoiceNum";
      var accField1 = "VendorID";
      var company = "MyCompany";
      var ProcLvl = "5";
      var sINVNumber = "7567567567";
      var sVenNumber = "36456346436";

      if (sINVNumber == "") {
        portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox("Please inquire on a valid invoice first. ", "ok", "info", window, false);
        return true;
      }
      //var encINVNumber = 

encodeURIComponent(portalWnd.strTrim(sINVNumber));

            var s =` http://${onBaseServer}/OnBaseLinkWebPOC/AccLogin.aspx?DBID=${appName}&ScreenID${screenID}&Company=${company}&ProcLvl=${ProcLvl}&${accField1}=${sVenNumber}&${accField}=${sINVNumber};`

          //portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox(s,"ok","info",window,false)

          window.open(s, "My Invoice");
          console.log(s);
          return true;
        }

        ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument();



try using the latest es6 template literals
```